# How can I learn *practical* natural language processing?

Tags: java, frameworks, nlp

I have some background in Java, Pascal, PERL, SQL, & R and would like to find a reasonably least resistance path from that background to doing automated or semi-automated extraction of concepts from text and turning the result into something statistically analyzable (willing to learn new languages if needed).  I imagine I will need to perform some NLP tasks on a few thousand pages of text, particularly POS processing, identification of noun phrases, word sense disambiguation.  The latter, I believe, may require semi-supervised machine learning for accuracy.  The question I have is where to start learning **practical** NLP?  Taking a course or reading NLP books seem to involve getting into far more detail about how NLP tasks are conducted than I need now--I just need to know what it does, how accurate it is, and what alternatives there are.  Jumping into some existing NLP framework seems to get me stuck.  I've used GATE for POS processing, but the output was either in XML, which I have no idea how to further process, or in postgresql, which was a bear to manipulate w/ SQL to generate statistical data.  Also, at the time, GATE had no good method for extracting word sense.

Comment: Try using the NLTK library in Python which has implementation of several NLP algorithms.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question would be much more readable if you used whitespace.

Comment: Thanks Johan!  White space as in carriage returns?  The comment seems to get sent when I use a carriage return....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLTK is the way to go for you. :)

Also, if you are interested in implementing algorithms like LDA, LSA, etc. I would recommend to go with `gensims`

Answer (score 2):

[OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/) will enable you to leverage your existing Java knowledge. But there is no question @neeagl's suggestion of [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) is an outstanding one. Also, Python might be the best language to just get something going.

Comment: Have to say the 1st page of the nltk.org website gives some simple examples that make an impressive case for using NLTK & the free book looks very handy!  Not quite sure how to turn the chunked text into

Comment: Let me know if you need any help with NLTK.

Comment: Thanks neeagl!  I guess I have 2 questions:  I see that NLTK has word sense disambiguation algorithms.  But these seem to be fully automated and I'd guess the accuracy is modest (mildly better than picking most frequently used sense).  Do you know if there is a way to connect NLTK output to a semi-supervised word sense algorithm?  Also, if I want to go from the chunked text output to a stats file (e.g., variables that indicate the presence of a compound noun in a noun phrase), I guess that's for me to code?  Might be easy w/ Python.

Answer (score 1):

I've now had some experience with NLTK, the NLTK book, and the Stanford CoreNLP software, so I think I can add something useful in terms of how someone with practical interests should approach doing NLP.

My initial goal was to get some NLP tasks done and done well without needing to learn the nitty-gritty of how NLP does what it does (at least outside special interest areas).  With that goal, I likely should have simply started with the Stanford CoreNLP software.  It does more or less state of the art work, and learning how to put text into the software and get output is very straightforward.  NLTK is shy of CoreNLP in terms of quality of output and, for everything other than statistical collocation analysis (as far as I can tell), CoreNLP has a broader range of practical algorithms.

For example, in NLTK to chunk noun phrases, you need to program regular expressions or train a machine learning routine.  For parsing, you learn a multitude of ways of doing parsing and there are multiple grammars you can apply.  It's not clear to me which ones are best or whether what is available is state of the art.  In CoreNLP, you request a parse and you get what looks like very competent parsing.  The parsing identifies noun phrases, so my problem of IDing noun phrases is solved.

No doubt I need to eventually learn more about whether I am doing things as optimally as I should and whether I should train to specific data.  But I have a practical problem on hand and need to see if NLP can begin to address that problem.  I can circle back later and fill in gaps.  So, for now, CoreNLP used simplistically meets my needs.

CoreNLP will kick results out to XML or to annotation objects, so I will need to learn how to deal with these in Java.  And, I'll need to learn how to do some additional processing and add results.

The NLTK book would be an excellent hands-on book for someone interested in learning some of the nitty-gritty of NLP.  And, it was useful to see how language data was represented and manipulated by NLTK, though ultimately things are handled differently in Java, which is where I'm focusing my attention for now.  Java is also perhaps more useful for big, complicated tasks--the language is more structured and an order of magnitude faster than Python.  Finally, CoreNLP has a pipeline--you put in text, indicate what kinds of annotations you want, and out comes a final product.  In NLTK, it's less clear how to stack a number of different annotations (say POS, lemmas, parsing) on top of each other.